# Get all information about a person from when he or she was XX years old

Tags: sql, mariadb, date

I store a person's birthday as `DATE` in the database. If I go to the page `/person/10/age/25`, I want to get all data for this person that are from when he or she was 25 years old, based on his or hers birthday.

Currently, I'm using `FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(date_birth, '%Y-%m-%d')) / 365.25)` to get the age of the person based on `DATE`. But I want to some how reverse this formula (correct word?) so it is getting all the information about the person, from when he or she was 25 years old.

SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM images AS i
JOIN people AS p
ON i.id_person = p.id
WHERE p.id = '10'

# new line
AND i.date_taken = DATE_ADD(p.date_birth, INTERVAL 25 YEAR)

# old line
# AND p.date_birth = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(date_birth, '%Y-%m-%d')) / 365.25)
```

Here's how the database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_person` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_taken` date DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `date_birth` date NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d1cfc/2

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not related to your question, but if birth_date is a date, you don't need the `str_to_date` function.

Comment: Thank you for saying this to me, @DanBracuk :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up: don't do date manipulation this way (especially using 365.25 as a year multiplier)  Instead, take a look at the DateAdd function.

(Ugh, had a long post typed out, and only after posting noticed that you're in MariaDB instead of MSSQL)

Anyway, you're looking for something like:

DATEADD(dateOfBirthValue, INTERVAL 25 YEAR)

... this will add 25 years to a specific date value.  Hope that helps - I can't really post a code snippet because I'm not familiar with the ins-and-outs of MariaDB (but I *do* know that you're going to want to use DateADD instead of manually calculating out days.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The SQL query in my updated question does not give any data though.

Comment: That's because you're looking for an exact date in your query.  Instead, you want to do DATEADD(dateOfBirthValue, INTERVAL 25 YEAR) to get the *start* of your records, and then something like DATEADD(dateOfBirthValue, INTERVAL 26 YEAR) to get the *end* of your date range.  I mean, it's not like it has to happen exactly on their 25th birthday to be relevant, right?  Just something that happened during any of the days they were "25 years old".

Comment: Very nice! I didn't think about that :P Many thanks!